# Principiante ¿Porque una variable me da como resultado 0?

Tags: java

Estoy intentando resolver este ejercicio a ver si me pueden ayudar...

Codifica un programa Java que lea las temperaturas del mes de Enero y calcule y visualice:

> - Temperatura media
> - La temperatura más baja
> - Cuantos días han tenido temperaturas superiores a la media

Mi problema es el siguiente.Cuando intento sacar la temperatura mas baja, me saca siempre 0 y no se porque. Debería de sacarme el valor mas bajo. Gracias por la ayuda de antemano...

```
public class ejercicio {

    static Scanner leer = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int cont=0;
        double mediaTemperatura = 0;
        int Array[] = new int[5];
        int baja = Array[0];



        for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
            int dia=i;
            System.out.println("Dime la temperatura del dia " + dia);
            Array[i] = leer.nextInt();
            mediaTemperatura += Array[i];
            if (Array[i] < baja) {
                baja = Array[i];
            }
        }
        mediaTemperatura = mediaTemperatura / Array.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
            if (Array[i]>mediaTemperatura){
                cont++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("La temperatura media es " + mediaTemperatura);
        System.out.println("La temperatura mas baja es:" +baja);
        System.out.println("Hay " + cont + " dias con temperatura mayor a la media");
    }
}
```

Comment: El problema es que inicializas la variable baja cuando la variable Array todavía no tiene valores (en la línea int baja = Array[0]). Una posible solución es poner un valor irreal y extremadamente alto, por ejemplo int baja = 1000.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Lo solucione!

Answer (score 1):

La primera ocasión estas asignando a `baja` el valor `Array[0]` que en realidad es 0, por lo tanto si escribes un valor mayor a cero nunca se asignará valor a `baja`:

```
if (Array[i] < baja) { //baja tiene el valor de 0.
    baja = Array[i];
}
```

Cambia el valor de inicialización de `baja`:

```
int cont=0;
double mediaTemperatura = 0;
int Array[] = new int[5];
//Inicializa con un valor que no sea cero y sea mayor a la max temperatura.
int baja = 100; //Array[0];

for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
    int dia=i;
    System.out.println("Dime la temperatura del dia " + dia);
    Array[i] = leer.nextInt();
    mediaTemperatura += Array[i];

    if (Array[i] < baja) {
        baja = Array[i];
    }
}
mediaTemperatura = mediaTemperatura / Array.length;

for (int i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
    if (Array[i]>mediaTemperatura){
        cont++;
    }
}
System.out.println("La temperatura media es " + mediaTemperatura);
System.out.println("La temperatura mas baja es:" +baja);
System.out.println("Hay " + cont + " dias con temperatura mayor a la media");
```

Comment: Gracias,lo solucione!

Comment: hola @Airsa97 recuerda que cuando una respuesta te da solución a el problema, la debes aceptar por que asi se entiende como finalizada la pregunta y ayuda a encontrar contenido de calidad a otros usuarios